# BottomSheet not taking swipe animation with Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a bottom sheet that I need to swipe to show it, and tab into it to open it, I have done this

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.awesomeproject.android.authentication.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment" />

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:name="com.awesomproject.android.BottomSheetFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment" />

</navigation>
```

Fragment

```
class BottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment, container, false)
}
```

### R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Order Details"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="₹435.00"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Paneer Tikka 1x2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Delivery Address"
        android:textColor="#444"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flat No 404, Skyline Apartments, Vizag - 500576" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#000"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added it to the fragment I want it to swipe like this

```
<include
android:id="@+id/container"
layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout"/>
```

Now, I want this behaviour

[image]

But in order to open the fragment with navigation components I need to put a click listener

```
container.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.bottomSheet)
        }
```

To open the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` when I click the included layout in my fragment

[image]

There is a way to swipe the bottomsheet and open the fragment with a smooth transition like the first gif with navigation components or do I need to do it this way only ?

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog[Fragment]` is actually a `Dialog`, like `AlertDialog`. That is, it's a whole separate window that is only added on-screen when it's programmatically shown. That unfortunately means that there is no way to swipe it open, because the `Dialog` is dismissed when it's hidden. You would need a `CoordinatorLayout` in your `Activity`, with a `BottomSheetBehavior` on your layout nested in it; a "regular" bottom sheet. I'm not sure that you can integrate that with the Navigation component, though. I'm not very familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will see what to do